# ExecComp - Vectorize Bug? 2.4.0

Tags: openmdao

Sample code from the manual is below.

If the vectorize=True is there I get an error :

comp: arg 'vectorize' in call to ExecComp() does not refer to any variable in the expressions ['y=3.0*x + 2.5']

i assume the newest version does not have this flag?
and can i use np.diff in the execcomp

```
import numpy as np

from openmdao.api import IndepVarComp, Group, Problem, ExecComp
p = Problem()
model = p.model
model.add_subsystem('indep', IndepVarComp('x', val=np.ones(5)))

model.add_subsystem('comp', ExecComp('y=3.0*x + 2.5', vectorize=True, x=np.ones(5), y=np.ones(5)))
model.connect('indep.x', 'comp.x')

p.setup()
p.run_model()

J = p.compute_totals(of=['comp.y'], wrt=['indep.x'], return_format='array')

print(J)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vectorize option was added after the latest OpenMDAO version was released, so in order to use it you'll have to either wait until the next release, or install using the latest commit to the OpenMDAO github repository.

To answer your second question, the np.diff command is not currently available in ExecComp.  You can submit an issue to the OpenMDAO github repository at (https://github.com/OpenMDAO/OpenMDAO/issues) if you'd like it to be made available.